# Redis Delete Keys

Tags: redis

How can I delete keys with part of the key name less than a certain number. For example I have the key of type:

```
keyname:20140418:item
```

Here 20140418 means that the key was generated on April 18th, 2014. How can I delete all keys with values less than todays date?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SCAN`](http://redis.io/commands/scan), in combination with [`DEL`](http://redis.io/commands/del).

With a proper batch size (for `SCAN`), this does not hinder other Redis clients.

> *OP:* "less than todays date"

-> This isn't straightforward in a wildcard for `SCAN`. Either walk all dates individually, or apply client-side logic to the `SCAN` results. I advice the latter.

As a speed improvement, while respecting client concurrency performance, you can use non-transactional [pipelining](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining) for the `DEL` command.

Hope this helps, TW